# angularJS datatables performance

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I am trying to render a datatable on Angular with over 10000 rows pulled from an API. Performance is very slow and my browser keeps crashing.
I came across different opinions: Lazy loading, ng-table, bindonce...
What would be the best option?
I am using angular-datatables version 1.9.4 http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should pay attention to this post :

[How does data binding work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs)

And especially the point of avoiding loading more than 2000 binded data.

In practice the options are :

1. bindonce or equivalent (seems not working in your case)
2. rendering a limited set of rows and loading data by infinite scroll 
   (this impact the UX)
3. use another framework for rendering your views (react ?)